# Locate or find holes tool in QGIS for polygon shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, geometry, holes

I want to locate or highlight all the holes (invalid interior rings that do not connect at all vertices and edges) and redundant geometry in a polygon shapefile in QGIS so that I can go back and manually correct all the vertices and geometry. I do not want to use the "Delete Holes" tool because I want to do it manually.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to demonstrate which you mean by "holes", since there are valid "interior rings" and invalid interior rings, and both overlaps and underlaps that damage topologic completeness.

Comment: @Vince edited as requested

Comment: Well, no. What makes them invalid? **Valid** interior rings also to not connect at edges. I was really looking for a demonstration. A graphic. If you can't define this mathematically, you can't do it manually.

Comment: Do you mean like the first polygon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uCM9.png ?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily find all invalid polygons by using the ["Check validity"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#check-validity) tool on the layer. In the output file with invalid polygons of this tool, there will also be a column that specifies why it is invalid:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use QGIS expressions with functions [`interior_ring_n()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#interior-ring-n), [`exterior_ring()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#exterior-ring) and [`is_valid()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#is-valid) to get polygons that have holes and/or are invalid/vaild. Combine them to fit your needs like identifying or deleting holes. You have different options as you can see below.

Alternatives are [Check validity tool](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#check-validity), [Geometry Checker Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html) and [Topology Checker Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html).

#### Automatically delete all holes from polygons

Use [Geoemtry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) ([see here for both options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) with this expression:

```
make_polygon (exterior_ring ($geometry))
```

#### Select polygons with holes

To identify polygons with holes, use [Select by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#automatic-selection) and expression function [`interior_ring_n()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#interior-ring-n) to return the first interior ring and if this indeed returns a geometry (and is not `NULL`), you know the polygon has interior rings.

```
 interior_ring_n ($geometry, 1) is not NULL
```

Alternatively, use [`num_interior_rings()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#num-interior-rings) function:

```
num_interior_rings ($geometry) > 0
```

#### Show holes

To show holes, use the following expression with Geometry Generator to create a point marker for each hole (thus showing even very small, invisible holes):

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (1, num_interior_rings ($geometry)),
        point_on_surface(make_polygon(interior_ring_n ($geometry, @element)))
    )
)
```

*Each point shows a hole:*
[image]

#### Select polygons that are (in)valid

To identify polygons that are valid, use [`is_valid()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#is-valid):

```
is_valid($geometry)
```

#### Select polygons with holes and validity combined

If you combine both, you can identify polygon with holes that are not valid:

```
interior_ring_n ($geometry, 1) is not NULL and 
NOT is_valid($geometry)
```

*Two polygons with invalid interior rings are selected (yellow); the polygon on the upper left is invalid, but not selected as it has no holes:*
[image]

#### Show invalid interior rings as geometries

```
collect_geometries(
    array_filter(
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (1, num_interior_rings ($geometry)),
            case
            when not is_valid (make_polygon(interior_ring_n ($geometry, @element)))
            then make_polygon(interior_ring_n ($geometry, @element))
            end
        ),
        @element is not NULL
    )
)
```

*Blue polygons are invalid interior rings:*
[image]

#### Show invalid interior rings as point markers

Alternatively, you could in line 7 you could enclose the `make_polygon()` function into a `point_on_surface()` function to get a point marker where you have invalid interior rings. Like this, you can see even extremely small interior rings (ke slivers) when zoomed out:

*Red arrows shows location of point marker where an extremely small, invalid interior ring is located:*
[image]