# How to identify holes of missing geometry enclosed within a polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, geometry, holes

I want to locate or highlight all the holes (invalid interior rings that do not connect at all vertices and edges) and redundant geometry in a polygon shapefile in QGIS so that I can go back and manually correct all the vertices and geometry. I do not want to use the "Delete Holes" tool because I want to do it manually.

Some of the potential holes are very small, so it would take me a long time to find them all

Example image with one hole below

[image]

Comment: Please Edit the original closed question instead of adding a new one. [Locate or find holes tool in QGIS for polygon shapefiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/474397/locate-or-find-holes-tool-in-qgis-for-polygon-shapefiles) Note that your definition of *invalidness* needs work, since interior rings ("holes") **are** a valid part of most topologic datasets, as are external rings ("islands")

Comment: No, that was my previous question but I did not attach a picture like I did in this question. All of the geometry is valid in my shapefile

Comment: I don't understand the jargon of how to ask my question the way you want me to

Comment: And we don't understand your Question using our jargon in unknown ways. Interior rings *never* "connect at all vertices"; they, in fact, are forbidden from touching at more than one. Maybe you should start with the [shapefile specification](https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/sitecore-archive/Files/Pdfs/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf), so you understand what valid rings are, and then you can focus on how QGIS gives programmatic/manual access to the data structure.

Comment: The person who posted the answer below figured out what I was trying to ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this workflow:
[image]

My starting layer, some holes along the borders and inside:
[image]

1. Dissolve
   [image]
2. Delete holes
   [image]
3. Difference the Delete holes output with the start layer to create polygons where there are holes
   [image]

The output is one multipolygon, you might want to Multipart to Singleparts it to create individual polygons of each part/hole.